# Simple Line replace not working in Java

Tags: java

I've the below content in a text file named **Sample.txt**

```
This is line1
This is line2
```

and here I want to replace this new line with *and*, I mean the output should be like

```
This is line1 and This is line2
```

and my code is as below.

BufferedReader br = null;

```
try {

    String sCurrentLine;

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\Test\\Sample.txt"));
    int i = 0;
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String sCurrentLine1 = sCurrentLine.replaceAll("\\n+", "0NL0");
        System.out.println("Line No." + i + " " + sCurrentLine1);
        i++;
    }
```

When I'm printing this, I get the output as

```
Line No.0 This is line1
Line No.1 This is line2
```

please let me know how can I replace this new line.

Thanks

Comment: By definition `readLine()` reads _single_ lines and does not include the ending newline character.

Comment: is your problem about replace not working (and hence you cannot see `0NL0` in your result), or you simply want the output to be all in 1 line?  For latter, use `print` instead of `println`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to do a `replaceAll` The `BufferedReader::readLine()` method removes the `\n` character from the returned string in `sCurrentLine`. So all you have to do is append the returned lines.

Example:

```
try {

String sCurrentLine;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();// Declare a string builder object.
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\home\\Desktop\\Test\\Sample.txt"));
int i = 0;
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if(i>0) {
        sb.append(" and ");
    }
    sb.append(sCurrentLine);
    System.out.println("Line No." + i + " " + sCurrentLine);
    i++;
}
System.out.println("Appended output " + sb.toString());
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
String str = "";
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

    String sCurrentLine1 = sCurrentLine.replaceAll("\\n+", "0NL0");
    str = str + sCurrentLine1 + " and "; 
}
System.out.println(str.substring(0,(str.length()-5)));
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Friend, this works good, but I get null printed as first result and then the actual result. `nullThis is line1 and This is line2 `